# what are different preview report using excel preview and excel preview(using J ExcelApi) in iReports 2.0.2?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

i'm still new in Jasper reports.i still confuse what the different preview report using excel preview and excel preview(using J ExcelApi) in iReports 2.0.2.Which is more common that people use?. is there any effect when we generate the report?. Can anybody tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jasperreports supports multiple export formats (xls, pdf, csv, etc...). After developing a report using iReport, you can generate a report in any of those export formats. The best way to view those reports is using an external appliction that you can map. For example, xls report is tied with Excel and pdf reports are tied with Adobe Reader. The new version of iReport supports generation of these reports using the application itself (preview). However, what happens in the background is the same whether you view it with external viewer or internaly using iReport "preview". Personaly, I prefer to use external viewer. The exported reports are cached in the compilation directory.

Comment: your meaning is if i want to view my report, i must select "excel preview" or "excel preview(using J ExcelApi)". which is external?

Comment: "Excel preview" launches the external program linked to that format.